# Rails how to check which foreign key is found the most?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, foreign-keys

I'm building an app in which players can buy shares of a company. The player that owns the most shares in a given company is the president.
I have a company model that has a method check_president. This method is called whenever a share is bought or sold. 
I have a stock model that has an owner. the owner of the stock is stored through a owner_id foreign key. So for every stock there is a separate record with its own owner.
What is the best way to check the president of the company?

something like this:

```
 def check_president
    player_owned_stocks = ownstocks.where(ownable_type: "Player")
    if(player_owned_stocks != nil)
        *** find player with most stocks, if tied presidency should not change ***
        president_id = player with most stocks
    else
        president_id = nil
    end
end
```

Comment: Do the stock table have the owner_id and company_id? And also, "for every stock there is a separate record with its owner", is there any count in the stock in the Stock table, to find how much stock he had purchased?

Comment: stock table actually has a company_id (which is the company that issued the stock),  and a polymorphic relationship using ownable_type and ownable_id (because a stock can be bought/owned by a player OR a company OR even some other object). there is no count in the stock table. Each record only represents 1 stock.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
ownstocks.joins("LEFT JOIN players ON players.id = stocks.owner_id").select("COUNT(*) as total_stocks, players.id as id").group("players.id").order("total_stocks DESC").first.id
```

This will give you the id of the player with maximum stocks for a company. You can put this query inside your if condition.

Answer (score 0):

a way to do this is to generate a hash where key is `owner_id` and value is it's count on the table. Then using this hash to find the pair with maximum value. This will an array in the form `[k, v] => [owner_id, count]`. The first element of this array is your president_id

```
hash = player_owned_stocks.group(:owner_id).count
president_id = hash.max_by { |k,v| v }[0]
```

one liner

```
president_id = player_owned_stocks.group(:owner_id).count.max_by { |k,v| v }[0]
```

Comment: This looks like the way to go, but I need an extra step. When 2 or more players are tied for most shares, The president needs to stay the same. This needs to work with 2 or even a 4 way tie.